# Find the first link with given tag and open it (userscript)

Tags: javascript, href, redirect, userscripts

This seems a simple problem, still I cannot manage to find out how to solve it.

I'd like to write a greasemonkey userscript for a webshop what is doing the next when I open their site (what is basically a listing of items under each other).

- checking if there is any new items since my last visit 
  (in the html of the site there will be a "new " mark in their class)
  in case it finds 1 or more items with the new tag, go to the next step (else do nothing)
- redirect this main page to the first link with the "new " tag

So when I open  http://mywebsite.com/  I should be redirected immediately to  http://mywebsite.com/forsale/100009/  in this example.
But I don't know what will be the url, that's why a script needs to check the links. Only the first match I need (new items are always on top). Not old (without the new tag) and not new items under/after the first one.

This is how the website's source looks:

```
<div class="item new "  id="item_0" style="">
  <div class="item_click_overlay">
    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/forsale/100009/">
    <img src="http://mywebsite.com/pics/100009.gif">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item new "  id="item_1" style="">
  <div class="item_click_overlay">
    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/forsale/100007/">
    <img src="http://mywebsite.com/pics/100007.gif">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item  "  id="item_2" style="">
  <div class="item_click_overlay">
    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/forsale/100006/">
    <img src="http://mywebsite.com/pics/100006.gif">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item  "  id="item_3" style="">
  <div class="item_click_overlay">
    <a href="http://mywebsite.com/forsale/100002/">
    <img src="http://mywebsite.com/pics/100002.gif">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You usually want to include things you have tried in your code sample. Stack overflow isn't a place for someone to do your coding for you. That said, I have provided a basic example as an answer because I think your question could still be valuable to others.

Comment: I'm aware, sorry about that, but I've tried like 100 ways, looked everywhere for solution, and always got an error. I did not save my tryings, I did not see it necessary to copy some irrelevant codes. And yes, the answer will be valuable for users for sure, like I said I found this nowhere else. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this you mean?

```
var newLink = $( ".item.new:first" ).find('a:first').attr('href');
window.location.replace(newLink);
```

Or this without jQuery:

```
var newLink = document.getElementsByClassName('item new')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href;
window.location.replace(newLink);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The bottom one works fine! (It would be perfect if it could be faster, it is waiting longer than I thought, but nothing can be done I'm afraid?) Thank you again!

Comment: The wait is unavoidable, it is probably waiting until the DOM is fully loaded before executing your code.

Answer (score 1):

Shortened M.D.'s solution a bit, posting here as this also works:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('item new')[0].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].click();
```